# Find all k-sum paths in a binary tree

Tags: java, algorithm, programming-challenge, tree, interview-questions

**Description:**

Given a binary tree and a sum, find all root-to-leaf paths where each path's sum equals the given sum.

Note: A leaf is a node with no children.

[Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/path-sum-ii/description/)

**Code:**

```
class Solution {
    private List<List<Integer>> paths = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<List<Integer>> pathSum(TreeNode root, int sum) {
        traverse(root, sum, new ArrayList<Integer>());
        return paths;
    }

    private void traverse(TreeNode root, int sum, ArrayList<Integer> path) {
        if (root != null) {
            path.add(root.val);

            if (root.left == null && root.right == null && sum == root.val) {
                paths.add((ArrayList) path.clone());
            }

            traverse(root.left,  sum - root.val, path);
            traverse(root.right, sum - root.val, path);

            path.remove(path.size() - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a fine solution. I have a few minor comments.

- It's easy to overlook that `pathSum` doesn't clear the content of `paths`, which will affect the returned value from subsequent calls, which is likely to be unexpected by callers. In this online puzzle it doesn't seem to matter, but I think it's better to avoid any possible confusion.
- The `clone` with the cast is ugly. The `.clone()` method except on arrays is a bit controversial, with questionable benefits if any. I suggest to avoid it. You can replace it with a nice clean `paths.add(new ArrayList<>(path))`
- The signature of `traverse` would be better to use `List` instead of `ArrayList`.
- I would use an early return in `traverse`, to have less indented code.